# Add geometry Column in sqlite (QGIS) by using python code

Tags: python, sql, qgis

I'm trying to create a geometry column in a table which I created.

I found the following code:

```
cur.execute('SELECT addgeometrycolumn(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' %(table_name, geometry_column_name, EPSGcode, 'POLYGON', 'XYZ'))
```

but I always get the same error : no such column table_name

It seems that the addgeometrycolumn is not the same function that the one I found during my research. So please can someone help me to add a geometric column to an existing table?

Thank you for your attention to this matter!

Answer (score 0):

This error looks familiar to me.

Does the table exist?  If so, use it in the argument list.

Also, check that the data types are correct.  Some may be integers.

I looked here, but did not confirm:

https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.0/spatialite-sql-2.3.0.html

Just a few hints...

Katie U

Comment: I checked the sqlite documentation and there is always the same function AddgeometryColumn which take as first argument the table's name but when i try to put it in my python script it always told me that the first argument must be a column name...

Comment: When I directly run my sql query in the sql window (from database manager or sqlite plugin) this works but with the python script it doesn't. Is this possible that the cursor doesn't take into account the addgeometry statement?